# How to create shortcut in Desktop after install my wpf app

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, installation

I've done with my wpf app and deploy with the option "Install from a CD-ROM or DVD-ROM" option. At the end of the Publish Wizard it said that the shortcut will be added to Start Menu and nothing more. How can I make the shortcut automatically sent to Desktop right after installation?

Comment: Once you've created the shortcut, you can move it to [`Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=net-5.0) using [`File.Move`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.move?view=net-5.0) or similar.

Comment: There's more information about moving files in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-copy-delete-and-move-files-and-folders).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selecting the "Create desktop shortcut" option under Project->Properties->Publish->Options->Manifests in Visual Studio should give you a desktop shortcut:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is what I need